# Is this a valid markov chain?

Tags: markov-process

[image: Markov Chain]

I have the Markov chain presented in the image. It hast 4 states S=(1,2,3,4). The transitional probabilities are all $\frac{1}{2}$ and the direction from one state to another is given by the arrows.

Is there an error with the original problem? We have 3 arrows from state 2, so $p_{24}=1$, but $p_{21}=\frac{1}{2}$. Can you confirm that this is not possible?

Comment: Yeah, this is probably an error in the problem statement. The sum of probabilities on edges going out of every state must be one. Also having two edges from state 2 to 4 makes no sense, so probably one of them should be reversed, and then everything will be ok.

Comment: This chain--once the error is corrected--appears to be a special case of the one recently discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48467/what-is-symmetric-property-for-stationary-distribution/48522#48522.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you whuber and  sjm.majewski. The answer is, that the above figure is not a Markov chain.

Comment: I can't tell if this is supposed to be an answer to your question, or if this is a comment in response to the previous comments. Note that users are not typically notified based on mentions w/i answers; if you want to ping them, it is best to comment below their comments.

Comment: I will add an answer below their comments, but I also wanted to not leave the question unanswered, given the fact that the previous posters did not provide an answer themselves (just in comment form).